# Bootstrap Affix attach to right bottom

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to attach my menu to the right bottom using Bootstrap Affix, but I'm struggling to find a way

You should be able to see what I mean here - http://busstopcards.com

I've also tried to added a repeat-y background for the pole but can't get the column to fill the height - I think if anything these two elements are compromising each other

Thank
David

Comment: You want to attach the menu on the right side (greetings cards and so on) to different pages that display content on the left side?

Comment: Thats correct (its part of a template so is automatically repeated across pages)